# force Stop httpClient httpget?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

aim not able at all to Stop both  `httpClient` AND `httpget`

when i click on progress dialog `cancel` button the `Request` and `AsyncTask` shall Stop and abort but its not , the request still running until its finished

this is my `AsyncTask` Test code

```
public class getAlbuminfo extends AsyncTask<String,String, String> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog; 
    JSONObject data       = null;   
    boolean prependMore   = false;

    //Http 
    HttpClient httpClient;
    HttpGet    httpget;

    /**********
     * Begien
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        if ( onlypagenat == false )
        {
          progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
          progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
          progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
          progressDialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.opening_album));
          progressDialog.setButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              cancel(true);  
              finish();
            }});
          progressDialog.show();                    
        }     

       prependMore = appendMore;
       appendMore  = false;

    }   
    /**************
     * IF Canceled
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        Log.i("Http Response:", "Aborted");

        if ( httpget != null )
        {
          httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
          httpget.abort();
        }  
    }    
    /****************
     * Make Request
     */ 
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String response = null;
        String url      = Api.foruminfo.forum_api_url+"/album.php?albumid="+albumid+"&page="+page+"&onlypagenat="+(onlypagenat?1:0);

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpget    = new HttpGet(url);

        //Add Values User Headers and Cookies
        httpget.addHeader("Cookie", Api.forumCookies());
        httpget.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
               HttpResponse serverResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget);

               Log.i("Http HttpResponse:", serverResponse.toString());

               //Set Response
               response = EntityUtils.toString(serverResponse.getEntity());

              } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}


     return  response;
    } 
    /**********************
     * Done
     */ 
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

                  Log.i("Http HttpResponse:", response);

        if ( onlypagenat == false )
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();   
        }


    }   
  }
```

Any advice Please how to Full stop Get or Post `http` request in android !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [AsyncTask.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method has nothing to do with the cancel of a http request. `cancel(true)` only prevents that onPostExecute() will be invoked after doInBackground finished the job. Instead onCancelled() will be called.

If you wanna cancel a http request use [HttpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager.html)

```
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          cancel(true);
          httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
          finish();
        }});
```

Comment: Finally a genus has found the solution , Thank you very much :D its worked fine now , aim able to abort http request ;) Thanks again

Comment: Won't this then kill all connections in a connection pool? What about killing just the connection that is being used for that request so you don't kill any other requests that are running at the moment?

Comment: @KevinM With [httpGet.abort()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase.html#abort%28%29) you can close the actual connection without closing the whole client.

Comment: I just came across that exact thing a few minutes after commenting here. I also came across a different way to do what I needed to do. I will be using an ExecutorService with a Callable class that will do the Http request. The ExecutorService will be responsible for killing the process after a set timeout that you pass to the invokeAll method.